# Embedded H2 database: sql file is not executed

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, h2

I`m using Spring Data JPA with embedded H2 database. I have two sql files:

schema.sql

```
CREATE TABLE SINGER (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    BIRTH_DATE DATE,

    CONSTRAINT UQ_SINGER UNIQUE (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ALBUM(
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    SINGER_ID INT,
    TITLE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    RELEASE_DATE DATE,

    CONSTRAINT UQ_ALBUM UNIQUE (TITLE),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ALBUM FOREIGN KEY (SINGER_ID) REFERENCES SINGER (ID),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

data.sql

```
INSERT INTO SINGER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE) VALUES ('John', 'Mayer', '1977-10-16');
INSERT INTO SINGER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE) VALUES ('Eric', 'Clapton', '1945-03-30');
INSERT INTO SINGER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE) VALUES ('Jorn', 'Butler', '1975-04-01');

INSERT INTO ALBUM (SINGER_ID, TITLE, RELEASE_DATE) VALUES (1, 'The Search For Everything', '2017-01-20');
INSERT INTO ALBUM (SINGER_ID, TITLE, RELEASE_DATE) VALUES (1, 'Battle Studies', '2009-11-17');
INSERT INTO ALBUM (SINGER_ID, TITLE, RELEASE_DATE) VALUES (2, 'From The Cradle', '1994-09-13');
```

Database configuration:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    try {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScripts("db/schema.sql", "db/data.sql")
                .build();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Cannot create DataSource", ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

**The problem is:** `schema.sql` is executed while `data.sql` not. All test (find all data, find by id, insert, update, delete) passes successfully

### Logs

```
INFO     [main] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils:510 -  Executed SQL script from class path resource [db/schema.sql] in 47 ms.
INFO     [main] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils:444 -  Executing SQL script from class path resource [db/data.sql]
DEBUG    [main] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils:476 -  1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO SINGER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE) VALUES ('John', 'Mayer', '1977-10-16')
DEBUG    [main] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils:476 -  1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO SINGER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE) VALUES ('Eric', 'Clapton', '1945-03-30')
DEBUG    [main] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils:476 -  1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO SINGER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE) VALUES ('Jorn', 'Butler', '1975-04-01')
DEBUG    [main] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils:476 -  1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO ALBUM (SINGER_ID, TITLE, RELEASE_DATE) VALUES (1, 'The Search For Everything', '2017-01-20')
DEBUG    [main] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils:476 -  1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO ALBUM (SINGER_ID, TITLE, RELEASE_DATE) VALUES (1, 'Battle Studies', '2009-11-17')
DEBUG    [main] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils:476 -  1 returned as update count for SQL: INSERT INTO ALBUM (SINGER_ID, TITLE, RELEASE_DATE) VALUES (2, 'From The Cradle', '1994-09-13')
INFO     [main] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils:510 -  Executed SQL script from class path resource [db/data.sql] in 16 ms.
DEBUG    [main] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils:340 -  Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

It seems like `data.sql` is executed successfully, but I doesn`t see the data (in test methods) as long as I insert some.

**UPDATE:** I have following test methods (all they pass successfully, but in testFindAll() I don`t see any data):

```
@Test
void testFindAll() {
    List<Singer> singers = singerRepository.findAll();
    assertNotNull(singers);
    displayAllSingers(singers);
}

@Test
void testInsert() {
    Singer singer = createSinger();
    singerRepository.insert(singer);
    assertNotNull(singer.getId());

    displayAllSingers(singerRepository.findAll());
}
```

You don`t need to worry about SingerRepository implementation, it works properly (in testInsert() you can see singerRepository.findAll() and it works, I see inserted singer).

Comment: from the logs your code seems to be executing all the two sql files so what is realy the problem like where do you want help?

Comment: @AustineGwa I updated my question.

Comment: How is your unit test annotated? Are the scripts located in `src/main/resources/db/`?

Comment: @bdkosher yes, scripts located in `src/main/recources/db/` (schema.sql is executed successfully). _How is your unit test annotated?_ - test class has `@SLF4j` annotation (lombok project) and test methods simply annotated with `@Test`

Comment: @bdkosher also I have init() method in the test class annotated with `@BeforeEach`, it instantiates spring's application context and retrieves `SingerRepository` bean from context.